# How to change encoding for existing file with Vim

Tags: shell, vim, encoding, character-encoding, batch-file

here is a subtitle file on http://subscene.com/subtitles/crank/farsi_persian/281992. if you download it you will see some codes like:

```
1
00:02:05,360 --> 00:02:07,430
åßÊæÑ¡ ãÇ åäæÒ ÏÇÑíã ãí ÑÎíã¿
ÎæÈå

2
00:02:07,600 --> 00:02:10,956
áíæÓ! ãÇ ÏÇÑíã í ÇÑ ãíäíã Èå ¿
æ Ïíå åí æÞÊ ãä Ñæ ÕÏÇ äãíÒäí
```

the thing i expect is:

```
1
00:02:05,360 --> 00:02:07,430
هكتور، ما هنوز داريم مي چرخيم؟
خوبه

2
00:02:07,600 --> 00:02:10,956
چليوس! ما داريم چي کار ميکنيم بچه ؟
و ديگه هيچ وقت من رو صدا نميزني
```

i reached it by changing the file extension from srt to txt, opening it with chrome browser, chenging encoding to arabic windows and re save file contents by select all text.

i have no idea how to do this with vim, or shell script. i tried `:write ++enc=utf-8 russian.txt` or `set encoding` or `set fileencoding`, but no luck.

thanks, mona

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in **vim**:

after loading your file, don't do any modification. then you could do:

```
:e ++enc=cp1256
```

To save in utf-8, just

```
:w ++enc=utf-8
```

or you could do it in **shell**:

```
iconv -cf WINDOWS-1256 -t utf-8 problem.srt -o correct.srt
```

Comment: It is working, but this only changes the way the file is displayed, how can I sae the file with this?